# What is the exact definition of the expression 'A Rat's Chance'?

Tags: expressions

I started to learn English.
Watching series like popular 'The X-Files' etc is very useful.
In the 6th episode of the 10th season I found the expression 'A rat's chance'.
What does it mean?

Comment: It's a shortened form of "not a rat's chance in hell" and basically means that there's no chance of something happening.

Answer (score 2):

It means **"No chance !"** or so little - that only a rat would try - it's 0 chance at all.